# How can i make content into 2 columns only on Desktop

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So basicly on the desktop version the 4 buttons should appear in groups of 2 in a 2x2 manner. The problem is that on mobile each should have each individual row. I'm using bootstrap for the row/column manipulation and React for the front-end. Im usually working on back-end so i know nothing on the html css side.

```
<div class="flex-row h-75">
            <div class="d-flex col-sm no-margin">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end col-sm p-1 p-lg-3 no-margin">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 no-margin">
                        <Link to="/profile">
                            <img src={Profile} alt="profile"/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start col-sm p-1 p-lg-3 no-margin">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 no-margin">
                        <Link to="/logout">
                            <img src={Logout} alt="logout"/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex col-sm no-margin">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end col-sm-6 p-1 p-lg-3 no-margin">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 no-margin">
                        <Link to="/products">
                            <img src={Products} alt="products"/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start col-sm-6 p-1 p-lg-3 no-margin">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 no-margin">
                        <Link to="/about">
                            <img src={About} alt="about"/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out on my own, what Trisha said was semi-right. I changed the d-flex col-sm class to a row class then i changed the d-flex-es to col-lg-6 so its displayed in columns only on large screens. That worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
You need to use col-12 class for each element

Comment: using col-12 for each element just makes them bump out of the screen, mobile and desktop too, and doesn't even put them on separated rows

Comment: You need to change your html so that it isn't that nested. You need to have in your parent layer the class "row" (includes as properties display:flex) and after that you added the children columns, for desktop size for example "col-lg-6" and for smartphones "col-12". This is a good example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match

Comment: well isn't the <div class="flex-row h-75> right at the top the parent class?

Answer (score 0):

you can duplicate and make one for desktop with class 'd-none d-md-block' and for the small screen you can use class="d-block d-md-none"